# How to use ElasticSearch MinHash plugin in NEST

Tags: nest, elasticsearch

I want to use [MinHash](https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-minhash) elastic search plugin in NEST Elasticsearch.net.
How can I use minhash plugin in nest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create index with following mapping:

```
elasticClient.CreateIndex(descriptor => descriptor
    .Index("my_index")
    .Analysis(
        analysis => analysis.Analyzers(bases => bases.Add("minhash_analyzer", new CustomAnalyzer
        {
            Tokenizer = "standard",
            Filter = new[] {"minhash"}
        })))
    .AddMapping<IndexElement>(
        mappingDescriptor =>
            mappingDescriptor
                .Properties(p => p
                    .String(s => s.Name(element => element.Message).CopyTo("minhashvalue"))
                    .Custom(new MiniHashMapping()))));

class MiniHashMapping : BinaryMapping
{
    [JsonProperty("minhash_analyzer")]
    public string Analyzer { get { return "minhash_analyzer"; } }

    public MiniHashMapping()
    {
        Type = "minhash";
        Name = "minhashvalue";
    }
}

class IndexElement
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Index sample document:

```
elasticClient.Index(new IndexElement
{
    Message = "Fess is Java based full text search server provided as OSS product."
}, descriptor => descriptor.Index("my_index"));
```

Tell elasticsearch to include fields in response:

```
var searchResponse = elasticClient.Search<IndexElement>(s => s.Query(q => q.MatchAll()).Fields("*"));
```

You can get hash value from `searchResponse.Hits[..].Fields` or `searchResponse.FieldSelections`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Rob:- Thank you.This solved my problem.I would like to know one more thing.Is it possible to store ngram for minhash_value.If yes please let me know